# Envelope of circle

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Show that the envelope of circles at right angles to the radii vectors of $r^n=a^n\cos{n\theta}$ is

$$
r^{\frac{n}{1-n}}=a^{\frac{n}{1-n}}\cos{\frac{n\theta}{1-n}}
$$

I took a log on both sides and differentiated the curve twice but still not getting what has been given to be proved. I think I am going in the wrong direction. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand the question. I know what the envelope of a one-parameter family of curves is. Your family of curves is circles of a fixed radius? Centered where? All you've told me is that these circles are orthogonal to the radius vectors of these curves. The title is certainly not right.

Comment: @Sayantan I also cannot understand, You want an envelope of all curves on parameter $n?$